# About the sigma function and an interesting inequality.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, divisor-sum

Is it true $\sigma(A)$/$\sigma(B)$ > = (A/B) ;  given B divides A ?

Comment: Is what is on or off topic a matter of opinion?

Comment: Putting the question another way ; if B divides A then is B ($\sigma(A)$) > = A ($\sigma(B)$) ?

Comment: Let S(n) = $\sigma(n)$ as a 'shorthand'. If B S(A) > = A S(B) then B S(A) - A S(B) > = 0 ; S(A)S(B) + B S(A) - A S(B) - A B > = (S(A) S(B) - A B) ; (S(A) - A)( S(B) + B) > = (S(A) S(B) - A B). Therefore if B divides A then ( S(B) + B ) > = (S(A)S(B) - A B)/ (S(A) - A). This seems like an interesting result..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the question refers to the standard sum-of-divisors function $\sigma_1(n)$.  If $B$ divides $A$, we can write $A=Bk$ with $k$ integer. We clearly have $\frac{\sigma_1(A)}{\sigma_1(B)}=\frac{A}{B}$ when $k=1$ and $A=B$.

On the other hand, when $k$ contains a single prime factor (i.e., $k$ is a prime number), the set of divisors of $A$ includes all divisors of $B$, plus all these multiplied by $k$. Thus, we have

$$\sigma_1(A)=(k+1)\sigma_1(B)$$

and then

$$\frac{\sigma_1(A)}{\sigma_1(B)}=k+1>\frac{A}{B}$$

It is not difficult to show that this inequality is also true when $k$ contains more than one factor, as in this case the set of divisors of $A$ includes all divisors of $B$, plus all these multiplied by each possible combination of factors of $k$.